# Biostrings::getPromoterSeq returning multiple sequences for query gene ID

Tags: r

I am looking to download the promoter sequences (3kb upstream from start site) of several Arabidopsis thaliana genes.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Biostrings)
library(TxDb.Athaliana.BioMart.plantsmart28)
library(BSgenome.Athaliana.TAIR.TAIR9)

seqlevels(TxDb.Athaliana.BioMart.plantsmart28) <- seqlevels(BSgenome.Athaliana.TAIR.TAIR9)

genes <- c("AT1G01010","AT1G01020","AT5G67480","AT5G67500")

sequences <- transcriptsBy(TxDb.Athaliana.BioMart.plantsmart28, 
                               by="gene")[genes] %>%
  getPromoterSeq(.,
                 Athaliana,
                 upstream=3000,
                 downstream=0)
```

But there are a couple of curious results however:

```
> sequences
DNAStringSetList of length 4
[["AT1G01010"]] AT1G01010=AAAAAAGCTATCGCCTCGACGATGCTCTATTTCTATCCTTGTAGCACACATTTTGGCA...
[["AT1G01020"]] AT1G01020=TTTTTTTTTCCGACATGTTTCTTGATGTTCATCATCATTAGGCTTTTGTCACCATGTT...
[["AT5G67480"]] AT5G67480=TAATTAACCATGGAGTTAGACTGCTAGATCATATGCAGACAATCATTAGGTTTCTAAA...
[["AT5G67500"]] AT5G67500=TCCATATCAACCAAGTCTAGACCTTTCTAATCAACTGCTAAAGTCTGTATTCGCTTAG...

> sequences@unlistData
  A DNAStringSet instance of length 7
    width seq                                                      names               
[1]  3000 AAAAAAGCTATCGCCTCGACGATGCTC...GCTGACTTCACTGTCTTCCTCCCTCC AT1G01010
[2]  3000 TTTTTTTTTCCGACATGTTTCTTGATG...CCCATTTAGGGTTAAAACAGTAGCCC AT1G01020
[3]  3000 TTTTTTTTTCCGACATGTTTCTTGATG...CCCATTTAGGGTTAAAACAGTAGCCC AT1G01020
[4]  3000 TAATTAACCATGGAGTTAGACTGCTAG...CGCAGGTGGGTGTCTCTGTTGATGAT AT5G67480
[5]  3000 ACATGGAGATCGATCAGACCAAGAACA...TAGAGCATTGATTGATTCTTGTTCTT AT5G67480
[6]  3000 TCCATATCAACCAAGTCTAGACCTTTC...TATTGGCTTCGCTATTTATTTTCGTC AT5G67500
[7]  3000 TAGACCTTTCTAATCAACTGCTAAAGT...ATTTTCGTCTACCACGAGAAAAACAA AT5G67500
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting multiple sequences in the second case while the first gives me 4 sequences for the 4 queried genes?

Also, I'm finding that these sequences don't get exactly match the start and stop positions available on the TAIR website.

Is there a way to obtain the sequences precisely upstream/downstream to TSS (ATG sequence) using the Biostrings package?

Comment: A lot of genes have alternative promoters, so it shouldn't come as a surprise that a single gene lists multiple promoters. As to comparing the genomic loci, are you sure you're using the same genome assembly and gene annotation versions?

Comment: Oh that makes sense to me. But why would I get two different outputs? Also for the annotation, I've edited the code I've used. Please take a look.

Comment: Outputs seem to be consistent; `sequences` is a `DNAStringSetList` that contains multiple sequences per unique gene ID. In `sequences@unlistData` you have explicitly `unlist`ed those entries, which then results in multiple separate sequences for the same gene ID. As to the reference genome version: You're using the TAIR9 reference genome but the most up-to-date version is TAIR10 (which is the default version on [https://www.arabidopsis.org/](https://www.arabidopsis.org/)). TAIR9 coordinates won't match TAIR10 coordinates!

Comment: Thanks Maurits. I suppose the follow up question is, how would I be able to obtain the upstream sequences (say 1kb) from the TSS (ATG sequence) using Biostrings?

Comment: And as far as the TAIR9/10 issue goes, Bioconductor lists the TAIR9 BSGenome as its latest version!

Comment: The Bioconductor reference genome packages do not always refer to the most up-to-date assembly versions! Don't take this the wrong way, Anurag, but these are all fairly simple (follow-up) questions that you should be able to answer yourself with a bit of googling. There's nothing wrong with TAIR9; the only thing to keep in mind is that it's *not* the most recent assembly, and you *can't* use TAIR9 coordinates in a TAIR10 assembly. The promoter sequences you have *do* correspond to sequences upstream of the start codon. But they won't be the same ones as from a TAIR10 assembly.

Comment: I should figure this out then. Thank you for your kind advice!

Comment: @AnuragN.Sharma It's not true that one can find easily informations on that. I am myself a Bioinformatics Postdoc. All Genome annotation is in a GTF file of your current genome. Go to https://emea.support.illumina.com/sequencing/sequencing_software/igenome.html and download your favorite genome. (Illumina kindly provides this - and it is up to date! - I have nothing to do with Illumina - but I like to use iGenomes - folder structure is always the same!). There in the sub folder `Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf` (search recursively within subfolders!) you have entire annotation.

Comment: In fact, the Bioconductor packages at the end also just use those annotation - but likely an older version. - In iGenomes you can get the newest versions. `install.packages("refGenome")` and read documentation of that.

Comment: Because it helps you to read-in gtf files into R data frames or GenomicRanges. It contains all chromosome and start and end positions of any exomes with the name of the gene. Read it in as GenomicRanges object. I switch between GenomicRanges and data.frames because some operaions (set operations, finding overlaps etc.) are much faster in GRanges than in data.frames but other operations are tedious to write in GRanges but easier and more familiar in GRanges.

Comment: Anyhow, once read-in gtf file of your genome version, you can easily select all 'genomic features' (exons) marked as 'promoter' and also get their gene name and get their start sequence coordinate - and manipulate those. Then with the help of correct BSgenome package version and the function https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/biomaRt/versions/2.28.0/topics/getSequence you can download fasta seuences using that coordinates.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim *"It's not true that one can find easily informations on that."* I guess it depends on how hard you look;-) You seem to have misunderstood OPs question though. His question was not "How to build a TAIR10 reference genome in R/Bioconductor". OP questions were: "Why do I have multiple promoter sequences per gene?" (because of alternative promoters) and "Why do extracted sequences not match TAIR10 sequences" (because TAIR9 != TAIR10).

Comment: [continued] To re-iterate: **There is nothing wrong with using TAIR9's `BSgenome.Athaliana.TAIR.TAIR9`; `getPromoterSeq` *will* give you promoter sequences upstream from the start codon.**

Comment: @MauritsEvers True, you can search hard. And probably there are commandline tools to do that even. - However, you have no fine-control possibilities when using such tools. - I just wanted to show OP a way which he can modify for himself and probably for other questions he has even, too. I have nothing against `BSgenome` - they are fine. It was more addressing `TxDb.Athaliana.BioMart.plantsmart28`. If one is using their `getPromoterSeq` function, one has to take what one gets. Probably they are very correct (very likely). But if one did it oneself, one can modify the procedure at libitum.

Comment: And I was not answering his questions - but just commenting - that is also why I am using the comments function here ;) . - And I was searching for such, too. But in the end I do it in exactly the way how I described (but in the mouse). Because I was not completely happy with what I found. - With the gtf file you have really full control what kind of features you select and how. - you can e.g. decide - okay fom each gene I take the most-upstream promoter (well just an example - I don't mean this is sth meaningful to do). Or one could also get for each promoter the transcrpt id belonging to it.

Comment: And the corresponding TSS number even. All this not possible if you use such ready-made function like `getPromoterSeq` - and most of all - you know exactly what you did when selecting - and you can change the procedure anytime.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim I very strongly disagree with your statement *"But if one did it oneself, one can modify the procedure at libitum."* This is exactly how research results become irreproducible, especially in our area of Bioinformatics. **If it can be avoided, you should *never* build your own [insert_method/annotation/referencegenome_here]**. It's hacky, not transparent and most likely not reproducible in the long term.That's the whole point of having Bioconductor and CRAN-managed packages. Use them! It's already difficult enough to ensure reproducibility without adding your own "custom scripts".

Comment: @MauritsEvers Nowadays one has to publish all the code anyway. And what about those who write the CRAN and Bioconductor packages? I began to write and as soon I have sth useful I will make a package out of it ... true what you say and not true. I don't buy "don't reinvent the wheel" philosophy. Sometimes you have to reinvent the wheel! sharkwheel.com (these wheels look differently - roll for longer time and in a more stable manner) ;)

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim I think we won't be able to agree on this one. I'd say: "Never re-invent the wheel!" Ever. Writing little packages out of your scripts don't ensure reproducibility or robustness. You should just take a look at the plethora of CRAN/Bioconductor zombie packages that were created by some PhD/PostDoc researcher without formal training in code development and who has since then long moved on. On top of that, publishing code is far less often done that you state. That's exactly the core of the problem. Let's leave it at that. I feel that we've "abused" OPs post long enough:-)